# How can I create custom issue filter equivalent to agile board column?

Tags: agile, jira

I have an agile board with column called "To Do" - see random example below. In this column I have now 2 tickets.

[image]

I would like to create my own issue filter ("Favourite filter") with equivalent results as in mentioned column.

I know that in column "To Do" are always issues with status `open`, but in project we have more `open` issues not only 2. We are in running sprint, so maybe this is also something I need to care about.

I tried to search, but I have no idea what field to use. Is not `status`, is not `type` of issue....

What is the query for filtering this agile board "label/name"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on the query that the board itself depends on. You can identify it by going to the board and selecting the "Board" drop down in the top right, then click "Configure". From there, select "General" configurations on the far left. The second field from the bottom is your Filter Query that determines what is shown on the board.

Next you have to figure out what statuses are associated with the column that you want. On the far left on the same board configurations page, you select "Columns". It's on this page that you can see all the statuses that are in the "To Do" column.

Last thing is to put them together and restrict it to issues in an open sprint. You take the filter query and add `AND Status in (<status1>, <status2>) AND Sprint in OpenSprints()` for each status that you found in the column.

Comment: No, Is not like this, I would like to create filter with same results as in column "To Do" (is not status, is column name on agile board), I'll rewrite my question later this day, with example.

Comment: @areim I've edited my answer to address your question's edits. Let me know if I still have the wrong idea of what you're asking.

Comment: You answer was totally helping me with my problem! Only thing missing is `AND Sprint in openSprints()` because there are more open issues available. You can add this option to your answer if you want. I inspired from @Barnaby Golden answer

Comment: I've edited the answer to include Barnaby's answer for completeness. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a JQL that selects the project, then selects the active sprint and finally selects the status of "To Do".

Something like this:

project = "my project" and sprint in openSprints() and status = "To Do"

Comment: Thanks a lot for `sprint in openSprint()`, this helps me, but your answer without @Aaron F answer was for me unclear :(. Upvote for you.

Comment: That's fair. Aaron's answer was a good one.